# fitting a sinusoidal function with python/gnuplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, gnuplot, curve-fitting

I have a problem with fitting this curve with both gnuplot and python.

The file I want to fit is [here](http://files.fm/u/kptucut). I want to fit it with a simple sinusoidal function as the followed:

`a+b*sin(c*x+d)`

I have as a result in both fitting method of gnuplot and python:

[image: gnuplot version]
[image: python version]

A part from the small difference in the x-scale, the one in python is rescaled, both figure give to me an incorrect fitting.

Comment: You need an appropriate initial guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that your data covers several cycles, and that your points are reasonably randomly distributed:

- the average (mean) y-value is a good guess for `a`
- the standard deviation of a sine wave is `1/sqrt(2)` of the peak, so a good guess is `b = sqrt(2) * stddev(data)`
- `c` is most easily found from the first strong peak in an FFT of your data